# RxJava count() when one of two observable is not compled

Tags: rx-java2

I want to count items from `stream` `Observable` when `trigger` is not completed. I want to update View by size of `stream` when `trigger` occurs. As long as `trigger` not completed `Consumer` not invoking `accept()`. How I can resolve it?

```java
    Observable<Long> trigger = Observable.interval(2000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    Observable<Long> stream = trigger
            .flatMap(new Function<Long, ObservableSource<?>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<?> apply(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                    return Observable.just("A", "B", "C"); //completed observable
                }
            })
            .count()
            .toObservable();

    stream.subscribe(new Consumer<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Long size) throws Exception {
            Log.e("Elements: ", size.toString());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a rolling count with `scan`:

```java
Observable<Long> trigger = Observable.interval(2000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

Observable<Long> stream = trigger
        .flatMap(new Function<Long, ObservableSource<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<String> apply(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                return Observable.just("A", "B", "C"); //completed observable
            }
        })
        .scan(0L, new BiFunction<Long, String, Long>() {
             @Override public Long apply(Long a, String b) {
                 return a + 1;
             }
        })
        ;

stream.subscribe(new Consumer<Long>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Long size) throws Exception {
        Log.e("Elements: ", size.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: In this case `size` is amount of every item. I would like to count each time size of this Observable: `Observable.just("A", "B", "C")`. In this case it should be always `3`.

Comment: How about applying `count()` on those `just`s? "But it no longer compiles" -> `flatMapSingle`.